# Updating Ubuntu 14.04.iso

Tags: updates, reinstall

I have had to reinstall Ubuntu from iso and was wondering now that I have updated all the files etc, is there away that I can add these updated files to the iso so next time I have to do a reinstall then atleast I will have a reasonably upto date iso file. Yes I know I can download .iso from site but this doesn't help me learn new commands etc.
Thanks peeps for your help

Comment: You could do it manually, by extracting the ISO and putting all the packages in, but I don't think there's a unified command to do this.

Comment: What commands would I use as I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux and still cant get windows commands out of my head, where are packages installed to etc

Comment: I'm essentially saying it's not possible,

Comment: As far as i know, there isn't a way to do that !

Comment: Ok no worries, something to play about with plus no doubt as a noob ill have plenty more questions to come. Thanks

Comment: You can at least download the periodically updated releases. For instance the 14.04 version has been updated twice and now when you download the 14.04.2 ISO it will be relatively updated.

Answer (score 0):

As an ITS release, ubuntu has point releases so you can download the last point release: 12.04.2 so you don'T need to download all updates.